# Initializing JHttpTransportCurl class

Tags: joomla-2.5, development, joomla-api, fix-my-code, curl

i am trying to call & get another url data.So is trying to create new instance of http class as follows -

```
jimport('joomla.http.http');
jimport('joomla.http.transport.curl');
$options = array();
$transport =  new JHttpTransportCurl($options); 
// Create a 'curl' transport.
$http = new JHttp($options, $transport);
$response = $http->get('http://api.example.com/shoes');
```

but it's not working as somewhere wrong in line 4. Please save my  time hoping this is the right way to make call to another API url.

Comment: Something wrong? Do you have any errors?

Comment: i set error reporting but no error shown but blank screen. by debug what i see is debug hangs in line 4, it's look like it can't create a new instance of jhttptransportcurl.question is how do i make call to external url using http class.

Comment: Well honestly I do not know why it is stacking there, but you can try to use `JHttpFactory` to get `Http`: `JHttpFactory::getHttp($options, 'curl')`

Comment: i am using joomla 2.5 and this class is where?

Comment: `/libraries/joomla/http/factory.php`

Comment: factory.php is not available in joomla2.5. But i found solution - $options = new JRegistry();

Comment: Hmm it is available - https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/2.5.x/libraries/joomla/http/factory.php. But I glad that you found a solution. BTW shame on me that I missed the constructor is requiring JRegistry. And strange that there are no errors displaying. Seems that they are in the logs.

Comment: I just don't see factory class in http folder in my j2.5.11. Anyway, simple thing i missed too!

Comment: 2.5.11? You should immediately update till 2.5.20, because versions prior to 2.5.19 are not secure.

Answer (score 3):

Just to have a valid answer.

The problem was in `$options` - it is an array, but `JHttpTransportCurl` constructor require `JRegistry` instance. So

```
$options = array();
```

should be changed to

```
$options = new JRegistry();
```